# Facebook Catalog Pixel Product Data Source - Remove Deleted Products

Tags: facebook, catalog, facebook-pixel

I have been creating facebook pixels and catalogs for ecommerce sites, the catalogs are connected to the pixels, and they can add, update and remove products automatically. Great.

Problem is I don't understand how the "remove deleted products" feature works.
This is found under the catalog "product data sources", in a connected pixel settings.

***Add New Products (on/off)**

***Update Existing Product Info (on/off)**

***Remove Deleted Products (on/off)**

Add/update is easy enough, when someone views a product page, the pixel fires, and the catalog gets the information.

But the pixel is not tracking or receiving information from our sites backend, it has no way of knowing when we deleted a product. 
How would it know?

I've been searching and searching for some kind of documentation describing this feature but am so far empty handed. *If someone knows where that is, that would be very helpful.*

**I've been talking to facebook support and it's just going in circles:**

**Facebook:** (First response after asking how this feature works)
"Thanks for being patient! It looks like that option would be for the Pixel to update any products that have been deleted from your website!"

**My reply:** "Right, but I was just wondering how it knows a product has been deleted?
As I understand it the pixel updates products as they are viewed on the website, so when a customer goes to a product page, it will add or update this product.
But what triggers a product deletion? "

**Facebook:** "When you delete the product, that is when it'll start implementing. So when you delete the product that what "triggers" it!"

**My reply:** "How does it know though? The pixel is not tracking our sites backend when we remove a product. 
Does it trigger if a previously existing product page 404's or redirects?"

**Facebook:** "When you remove that is not deleting when you delete that is when it will start tracking. It will know when you delete the product., it will not trigger if the product 404's or redirects."

I don't even know how to respond to the last one, I don't understand his answer at all.

Please help.

Comment: This is rather off-topic here, as it is not mainly a programming question. // Their last response seems to imply that products will be deleted, once your site indicates they are gone - by having the product URL, when requested, return a 404 or redirect elsewhere. (And without any backend access or an endpoint that could be “pinged” explicitly on product removal, that’s about the only thing technically possible.)

Comment: I tried really hard to find a better place to post this question. Apologies if this was wrong. Facebook support is bare bones at best and there's no forum for technical set up that I could find. If someone knows a better place to post please let me know, I would be grateful.